# Service worker update session expire time

Tags: angular, spring-boot, session, spring-session

In my application I am storing session in database using Spring JDBC session.

But as when Angular send ngsw request to server, it updating session  expire time. So my session never expires.

As there solution for this?

Angular ngsw request should not update session expire time.